# Fix categories in categoriaxis in dimple js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I am using Dimple js to make a bar chart with one bar for each day (Sunday, Monday...). The problem is that sometimes there won't be data for a few days but I would still want my chart to show all the days with a value 0.

How do I fix all the categories which should be shown on the axis?

Edit:
Here's a demo: jsfiddle.net/neme8got/
I want the chart to show the days not shown now with a volume 0.

Comment: can you add code demonstrating your current approach and how it's not working, in a jsbin or elsewhere?

Comment: Have edited the question to include the demo. Have a look...

Comment: How about providing the data with the 0 values? Like: `... {"Avg Volume": 0, "Day": "Monday"} ... `?

Comment: Yes, changing my Python backend to do this would have to be the last resort I take but was wondering if there was a simpler option in Dimple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's an easy way to do this with Dimple. The values shown on the x axis are provided by `axis._scale.domain()`. Unfortunately even if you set this to the full array of values, dimple overrides this during the `draw` [method](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/blob/master/src/objects/axis/methods/_update.js#L70), using the values plucked from the data from the category field string.

Your best bet is to change the data (on client side or server side) to add values for all the missing days. I've updated the example (using Underscore.js) to put in 0 values for the missing days :

```
var allDays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
var missing = _.difference(allDays, _.pluck(avg_by_day, 'Day'));
_.each(missing, function(missingDay){
    avg_by_day.push({'Avg Volume' : 0, 'Day' : missingDay}); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/neme8got/1/

Comment: The code is not working on my page.. Is there a conflict with jQuery?

Comment: are you including Underscore on your page? You could write the same code without it, it's just an easy way to find the missing values. Shouldn't be any conflict with jQuery.

Comment: No, haven't included underscore. Should I? Another possible reason might be that in my actual code, the avg_by_day is coming from a dictionary `var avg_by_day = all_data['avg_by_day'];`. Could this be the issue?

Comment: If you're not including Underscore then you will need to rewrite the section which finds the days not included in the value array. The "_" symbol is a reference to that library so any of those functions will need to be replaced with native functions / for-loops.